# How can i use datatables in my angular project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables

I need to use this library

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

For that i tried to install it in my angular project

In the documentation it says that we need to add two JS CDN files and one CSS

So i added them

*In my index.html file*

*In my component html*

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

*in the ts file*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatables',
  templateUrl: './datatables.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatables.component.scss']
})
export class DatatablesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable();
  } );
  }

}
```

but it is not working.I can't see the input - the styles of my table.How can i integrate this library with angular ?

I don't want to use this library `angular data tables`

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/individual-column-filtering

but i need the pure one

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/

because there are more option for advanced tables

Comment: on lifecycle hook ngOnInit your `#example` element is not available please refer `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: I tried that too, but it is the same :S